# How to sort varargs in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to do an exercise in clojure: given some numbers, pick the two largest number and sum the square of them.

Here is my code:

```
(defn square [x]
    (* x x))

(defn sum-two-largest-square [x y & rest]
  (apply + 
    (map square 
      (take 2 
        (reverse 
          (sort
            (to-array [x y rest])))))))
```

However, the code does not work. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what `to-array` is for, and not how it is meant to be used.

Replace `(to-array [x y rest])` with `(conj rest x y)`

Comment: Thank you very much, @noisesmith Yes, conj works. Would you please explain why I have to put rest in front of the conj, i.e. (conj rest x y), not (conj x y rest). (The latter doesn't work in this case.)

Comment: conj takes a collection as its first arg, followed by any number of elements to add to that collection. rest is a collection, x and y are not.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! Your answer and explanation are just to the point.

Answer (score 1):

@noisesmith got to the essence of why your code was not working. However, there is another (minor) issue here, which is that the structure of your function's arguments could be simplified.

The way you have it now, you are destructuring (separating) the arguments into `x`, `y` `& rest`, however you then essentially "undo" that destructuring by combining them back together into a single collection to be sorted. Why not just leave the arguments as a single collection, and then sort it, etc.? See below:

```
(defn sum-two-largest-square [& nums]
  (apply +
    (map square
      (take 2
        (reverse
          (sort nums))))))
```

On an unrelated note, whenever you have a chain of function calls like this, you might consider using a [threading macro](http://jdevuyst.blogspot.com/2013/11/thoughts-on-clojure-threading-macros.html):

```
(defn sum-two-largest-square [& nums]
  (->> nums
       sort
       reverse
       (take 2)
       (map square)
       (apply +)))
```

Comment: Oh, this is really enlightening - both varargs and the ->> macro. As an added bouns, if I put the argument as [& nums], it also accept less than two arguments. Thank you!

Comment: From the book  "The Joy of Clojure", the author wrote: "idiomatic Clojure code rarely uses the reverse function." Is there a way to improve this piece of code?

Comment: You could use [take-last](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/take-last), which returns the last two values in a collection. `(take 2 (reverse (sort nums)))` could be simplified as `(take-last 2 (sort nums))`.

Comment: Wow, Clojure is so powerful and interesting. Thank you Dave.